# Slow loading time of fonts in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I am testing my site using GTmetrix tool and I noticed that fonts are delaing site loading time. Site is on WordPress. I am using Elementor site builder and Porto Theme. As caching plugin I am using WP Rocket. I tried to use OMGF plugin to save Google Fonts localy but it is not working for me - it is hosting Google Fonts localy but still fonts are tring to load from google servers. Second thing is slowly loading of Font Awsome. Any suggestions how to make fonts load faster?

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/zapproject.pl/n4VYzQ3l

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon your question while I was googling for another OMGF support question.

I'm actually the author of OMGF. :)

To answer your question:

The basics of what you'd want to do is:

1. Download the stylesheet of the fonts from Google Fonts' API (fonts.googleapis.com),
2. Download the fonts mentioned in that stylesheet (fonts.gstatic.com/path/to/font.woff2)
3. Upload all these files to your server and change the paths in the stylesheet accordingly.
4. Then, in your theme's (preferrably a child theme) `functions.php` you'll add some code, like this:

```
function zapproject_local_google_fonts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('zapproject-google-fonts', 'path/to/stylesheet.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zapproject_local_google_fonts');
```

But, I'd much rather get OMGF to work with your theme (it's definitely compatible with Elementor. Many people run OMGF with Elementor) so feel free to hop over to the [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/host-webfonts-local/) and ask your question there! Please also provide the URL of the site you're trying to get OMGF to work with (it's only shown to logged in users.)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Daan, after some update of your plugin, now it is working well. All Google Fonts are loading localy. But thanks for support! :)

Comment: Awesome! That's good to hear. To help others, you could accept this answer, btw.